# How do I add eth0 on centos 5 that is using openvz

Tags: vpn, vps, centos5, openvz, pptp

I have a vps account with CentOS 5 installed. It uses OpenVZ for virtualization.

Now I'm trying to install pptp service ([using this guide](http://freehostinganswers.com/blog/how-to-install-your-own-vpn-server-in-5-mins-pptp-on-centos-redhat-and-ubuntu/)) on it. I'm currently on Step 6 but I don't see any `eth0` interface on my box.

I can only see `lo` and `venet0`. Now, how do I proceed with these steps if I don't have eth0 or ppp+:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p gre -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp+ -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o ppp+ -j ACCEPT
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use venet0. An OpenVZ machine has no ethX because it is a virtual adapter.

Comment: so i should use `iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT` right? how about the `ppp+` part?

Comment: I guess ppp+ will come up as soon as you start the service (next step). Otherwise it might be possible that it is not possible like this. OpenVZ is no real virtualization like KVM and VMware ESX. It is a Operating system-level virtualization where one kernel is used for multiple userspaces (containers).

Comment: It is working now.. I can connect but after a few minutes it disconnects me. I am going to check the ppp logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: Yep. But it still doesn't allow me awhile ago. will do so now. thanks!