# PPTP connection gets terminated after I try to do a speedtest

Tags: vpn, centos5, openvz, pptp

my connection to pptp gets terminated when I try to do a speedtest on [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net)

I have a vps account with centos 5 installed. It uses openvz for virtualization.

on `/var/logs/messages` the error says:

```
Aug  5 22:44:24 vps1 pptpd[902]: CTRL: Client x.x.x.x control connection started
Aug  5 22:44:24 vps1 pptpd[902]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Aug  5 22:44:24 vps1 pppd[903]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Aug  5 22:44:24 vps1 pppd[903]: pppd 2.4.4 started by root, uid 0
Aug  5 22:44:24 vps1 pppd[903]: Using interface ppp0
Aug  5 22:44:24 vps1 pppd[903]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Aug  5 22:44:27 vps1 pptpd[902]: CTRL: Ignored a SET LINK INFO packet with real ACCMs!
Aug  5 22:44:28 vps1 pppd[903]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Aug  5 22:44:29 vps1 pppd[903]: Cannot determine ethernet address for proxy ARP
Aug  5 22:44:29 vps1 pppd[903]: local  IP address 192.168.0.1
Aug  5 22:44:29 vps1 pppd[903]: remote IP address 192.168.0.101
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pptpd[902]: GRE: read(fd=7,buffer=6097c0,len=8260) from network failed: status = -1 error = Protocol not available
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pptpd[902]: CTRL: GRE read or PTY write failed (gre,pty)=(7,6)
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pppd[903]: Modem hangup
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pppd[903]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pppd[903]: Sent 134752 bytes, received 20812 bytes.
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pppd[903]: MPPE disabled
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pppd[903]: Connection terminated.
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pppd[903]: Exit.
Aug  5 22:44:35 vps1 pptpd[902]: CTRL: Client x.x.x.x control connection finished
```

I followed the instructions [here](http://freehostinganswers.com/blog/how-to-install-your-own-vpn-server-in-5-mins-pptp-on-centos-redhat-and-ubuntu/) on installing pptp

and this question is connected to [How do I add eth0 on centos 5 that is using openvz](https://serverfault.com/questions/528815/how-do-i-add-eth0-on-centos-5-that-is-using-openvz)

the question is: how do I make that speedtest page work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be either on the host or one the client side. Make sure port 1723 and protocol 47 are allowed on both sides.

Comment: my iptables rules are here: http://serverfault.com/questions/528815/how-do-i-add-eth0-on-centos-5-that-is-using-openvz i do believe 1723 is open. dont know how to check port 47 is though